# What types of streams need to be closed and why

Tags: java, iostream

In the book *Thinking in Java*, it was told that

> Notice that any code that opens a file guards the file’s close( ) call in a finally clause to guarantee that the file will be properly closed.

But what about other *sources* or *sinks*? At least currently I know that `stdin`, `stdout`, `stderr` and `ByteArrayInputStream`, `ByteArrayOutputStream` does not need to be *close*d.

As to the `stdin`, `stdout`, `stderr` I got two reasons for no need to be closed:

1. they are *singleton* in Java *run-time*
2. sink of `stdin` is the screen, source of `stdout` and `stderr` is keyboard, there is no sense to lose the connection to screen and keyboard

As to the `ByteArrayInputStream` and `ByteArrayOutputStream`, the Java doc told:

> Closing a ByteArrayInputStream has no effect. The methods in this class can be called after the stream has been closed without generating an IOException.

I guess it might be due to the fact that *array* is in the volatile memory other than the disk

But I am very sure about those analysis, so I would like to get more accurate and authorized answer about this and especially, **when we are designing streams by ourselves, when is it compulsory to close the stream and when not?**

**In the same time, I would like to confirm my reasoning about the unnecessary close is OK or, if anyone can give more reason, that would be appreciated**

Comment: Instead of writing a lot of finally blocks to close streams etc. you can also use Javas try-with-resources https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Comment: True, but it is still good to know why some streams like `stdin`, `stdout`, `stderr` do not need to be closed

Comment: Generally speaking, all streams need to remain open for as long as they need to be used. This includes streams you open yourself, and the system streams `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr`. The system streams are no exception. The same rule applies to them. The system streams are opened by the Java internals at the start, and they are closed by the Java internals at the end of your application. Why would you want to close them earlier?

Comment: By the way, beware of "wrapper" objects whose `close()` method closes the wrapped object. For example, if you create a `Scanner` initialised with `System.in`, then don't close it; otherwise, you'll inadvertently close `System.in`.

Comment: @Rui Absolutely - that's why I added this as a comment and not an answer, but it's still nice to know that Java helps reducing that multi-line pattern to something more reasonable.

Answer (score 2):

You need to close a stream if it uses an operating system resource that needs to be released. This is the case for files, network connections etc.

What's more, closing a stream guarantees that it is flushed, ie any data that has not yet been written will be. If you just exit your program without properly closing a stream, it's possible that eg a file is missing data.

That said, it's best to close *all* streams you're using. Note that "closing an ByteArrayInputStream has no effect" means that it doesn't have any negative impact either, so just close everything you don't need anymore.

As for the `System` streams (`in`, `out`, `err`), you don't close those because you haven't opened them, and some other place in the code might still want to use them.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation :) (Y)

Comment: *it doesn't have any negative impact either* - that's not a very good reason to "just close it anyway"

Comment: @TimCastelijns It's not a reason for closing, I stated those before. The point of that part was that there are none against closing if you don't need it anymore. In fact, Java's whole try-with-resources concept was introduced to guarantee closing of resources (although judging from the code I see here on SO, it seems most people don't actually know or use that).

Comment: it is still good to know why some streams like stdin, stdout, stderr do not need to be closed, so could anyone give more comments or answer on that as well

Comment: @Rui As stated in the answer, you should only close streams which you explicitly open. Since you didn't open stdin yourself, you are not responsible for closing it.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Thanks for your comment :) here I am confused about how to know if a stream is explicitly opened

Comment: @Rui "Explicitly" means that **you** wrote the code to open the stream, either with a constructor that opens it or calling `open()` directly.